# How to clear session of django session wizard

Tags: django

My code looks like this

```
class UploadWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'stl'))
    template_name = 'dummy.html'

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = []
        for form in form_list:
            if form.is_valid():
                form_data.append(form.cleaned_data)
        return render_to_response('done.html',{'form_data':form_data,})
```

After successful completion when i reload page it retain previous session. So i want to clear the wizard session just before return of done method.